# Querying JSON API in Objective -C

Tags: objective-c, json, api

I'm trying to query a JSON API in objective C and am wondering what SDK "tools" I will need. I know, for example, I will need to be able to send requests, get the data from that request then parse it. Basic structure and object documentation would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know about how to send request/receive data please check [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html). And to parse JSON please check [JSON Framework for Obj-C](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/).

Answer (score 2):

For sending requests and getting data I'd suggest [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) lib that provides (most likely) all network-related functions you'll need.

For JSON parsing check [this review](http://psionides.eu/2010/12/12/cocoa-json-parsing-libraries-part-2/) of several 3rd-party parsers available